# ¿Como llenar gridview asp.net c# sql desde behindcode?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, webforms, gridview

Tengo una aplicacion webform en ASP .NET con C# y quiero llenar un gridview desde el webform.aspx.cs.
Hay alguna manera de que se llene "solo" al entrar a la pagina, o debe ser solo con un evento click. Me podrian indicar como hacerlo.?
Agradecere mucho su ayuda
Gracias
Saludos

Comment: Hola si se puede .. tienes que indicar a tu grid que utilizara una fuente de datos podria ser un datatable .. haces el bindeo de datos y listo al cargar tu pagina contendra la informacion !

Comment: me podrias pasar un ejemplo si no es mucho pedir? es lo mismo en winform y en webform?

Comment: Tienen algunas variaciones, pero se podria decir que son similares ..

Comment: TE agrego el Ejemplo .. cualquier duda avvisame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este es mi Tabla o Grid en aspx (elimine algunas columnas por que uso muchas y son de mi trabajo .. )

```
 <asp:GridView ID="dtg_CutWeek" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="dtg_CutWeek_RowCommand">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Year" HeaderText="AÑO">
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <ItemStyle Width="50px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        </asp:BoundField>

                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="MONEDA" DataField="TC">
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <ItemStyle Width="60px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                    </Columns>
```

y para hacer el bindeo de los datos hago lo siguiente:

```
  dtg_CutWeek.DataSource = ""; // ELIMINO LOS DATOS QUE CONTENGA
    dtg_CutWeek.DataSource = dt; // ASIGNO NUEVOS DATOS QUE ESTAN EN MI dt
    dtg_CutWeek.DataBind(); //HAGO EL BINDEO DE LA INFORMACION ..
```

**dtg_CutWeek** ES EL NOMBRE DE MI GRID SI TE DAS CUENTA ES EL QUE USO PARA HACER REFERENCIA EN EL BACKEND

Answer (score 0):

En el **webform.aspx** debes tener algo como esto, donde **dgvDatos** es el identificador de tu GridView.

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgvDatos" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
</asp:GridView>
```

En tu codebehind **webform.aspx.cs** deberias hacer algo similar a esto.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgvDatos.DataSource = new Persona().Listar();
        dgvDatos.DataBind();
    }
```

Le puedes pasar un Dataset desde una BD, o directamete un coleccion de  datos como en este ejemplo.